# Get User Model Array List

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get payments array in GetUserModel it returns from nodeJs api with database information

I get with this:

```
  List? payments
      Future getCurrentUser() async {
        var loginDetails = await SharedService.loginDetails();
        email = loginDetails?.data.email;
        GetUserRequestModel model = GetUserRequestModel(email: email!);
    
        var currentUserInfo = await APIService.getUserInfo(model);
        balance = currentUserInfo.data?.balance;
        payments = currentUserInfo.data?.payments; //does not working
print(payments)
    }
```

currentUserInfo gives me everythings but I couldnt get payments array. print(payments)
gives me "Instant of payments" output how can I get payments array properly?

This is UserresponseModel:

```
import 'dart:convert';

GetUserResponseModel getUserResponseModelJSON(String str) =>
    GetUserResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class GetUserResponseModel {
  GetUserResponseModel({
    required this.message,
    required this.data,
  });
  late final String message;
  late final Data? data;

  GetUserResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json['message'];
    data = (json['data'] != null ? Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['message'] = message;
    _data['data'] = data?.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.balance,
    required this.date,
    required this.payments,
    required this.id,
  });
  late final String username;
  late final String email;
  late final int balance;
  late final String date;
  late final List<Payments> payments;
  late final String id;

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    username = json['username'];
    email = json['email'];
    balance = json['balance'];
    date = json['date'];
    payments =
        List.from(json['payments']).map((e) => Payments.fromJson(e)).toList();
    id = json['id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['username'] = username;
    _data['email'] = email;
    _data['balance'] = balance;
    _data['date'] = date;
    _data['payments'] = payments.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    _data['id'] = id;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Payments {
  Payments({
    required this.paymentCost,
    required this.paymentDate,
    required this.id,
  });
  late final int paymentCost;
  late final String paymentDate;
  late final String id;

  Payments.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    paymentCost = json['paymentCost'];
    paymentDate = json['paymentDate'];
    id = json['_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['paymentCost'] = paymentCost;
    _data['paymentDate'] = paymentDate;
    _data['_id'] = id;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

And this is the getUserInfo:

```
  static Future<GetUserResponseModel> getUserInfo(
      GetUserRequestModel model) async {
    var loginDetails = await SharedService.loginDetails();

    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ${loginDetails!.data.token}'
    };
    var url = Uri.http(Config.apiURL, Config.getUserInfoAPI);
    var response = await client.post(
      url,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: jsonEncode(model.toJson()),
    );

    return getUserResponseModelJSON(response.body);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are looking to print the payments data.

In the payments class you should add

```
@override
  String toString() {
    return ""; 
     // Return how you want to print the data. Here you could add for example the JSON output.  
  }
```

So the class will look like this

```
class Payments {
  Payments({
    required this.paymentCost,
    required this.paymentDate,
    required this.id,
  });
  late final int paymentCost;
  late final String paymentDate;
  late final String id;

  Payments.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    paymentCost = json['paymentCost'];
    paymentDate = json['paymentDate'];
    id = json['_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['paymentCost'] = paymentCost;
    _data['paymentDate'] = paymentDate;
    _data['_id'] = id;
    return _data;
  }
  @override
  String toString() {
    return "${this.paymentCost!} : ${this.paymentDate!} : ${this.id!}";
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this code.

Comment: Its good job !!